# Translating select distinct sql statement to activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm having issues translating this SQL statement to activerecord / ruby friendly code. Note that the end_at date is really DateTime.now.

```
SELECT DISTINCT events.id FROM events, channels
WHERE events.channel_id = channels.id AND events.end_at >= '2015-02-11 22:55:04'
ORDER BY start_at ASC, id ASC LIMIT 40
```

Suggestions?

Edit: The initial genesis of this problem comes from the fact that mysql doesn't support nested limits in subqueries for the app I'm working on. So pagination + this query was causing an error:

```
# channels is an activerecord relation, order_by_schedule is a scope
Event.where(:channel_id => channels).where{ end_at >= DateTime.now }.order_by_schedule.limit(channels.count * event_limit)
```

Comment: Why are you joining channels if you don't use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need to join `channels`, because you do not use them at all:

```
Event.select('DISTINCT id')
      where('end_at >= NOW()').
      order('started_at, id').
      limit(40)
```

Comment: I've made a quick edit above... I think my sql statement is actually incorrect, but the initial problem I've spelled out.